# How to use Collections methods(removeAll() and retainAll()) for two objects

Tags: java, list, collections, apache-commons

I expected to result below but actually not. Even though it worked when I tried to use String instead of Item Object.
I would like to know why the reasons about that and how to code in order to get expected result.Thanks.

```
EXPECTED
------------------------------
removed object are:
2
same object are:
1
3
add object are:
4
------------------------------
```

---

```
ACTUAL
------------------------------
removed object are:
1
2
3
same object are:
add object are:
1
3
4
------------------------------
```

---

```
package com.javastudy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionCompareToObjects {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  List<Item> before = new ArrayList<Item>();
  List<Item> after = new ArrayList<Item>();

  before.add(new Item(1L));
  before.add(new Item(2L)); // delete
  before.add(new Item(3L));

  after.add(new Item(1L));
  after.add(new Item(3L));
  after.add(new Item(4L)); // added

  List<Item> removed = new ArrayList<Item>(before);
  removed.removeAll(after);

  System.out.println("removed objects are:");
  for(Item item : removed){
   System.out.println(item.getId());
  }

  List<Item> same = new ArrayList<Item>(before);
  same.retainAll(after);

  System.out.println("same objects are:");
  for(Item item : same){
   System.out.println(item.getId());
  }

  List<Item> added = new ArrayList<Item>(after);
  added.removeAll(before);

  System.out.println("add objects are:");
  for(Item item : added){
   System.out.println(item.getId());
  }

 }

}

package com.javastudy;

public class Item {

 Long id;

 public Item(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't implemented equals() so ALL your Items are different objects some happen to have a field which is the same.

You need to implement equals.

I also suggest you use long instead of Long, unless you want id = null.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! I added equals method using Eclipse's code complement.

Comment: @yusaku - you are invited to mark the answer that has worked for you as accepted. (tick below the vote counter)

Comment: Oh sorry. I am not very familiar with this site yet.

Comment: Don;t forget to implement hashCode() when overriding equals()

Comment: @PSIXO if you are using a hash collection, which the OP isn't.

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the `equals(..)` method of your `Item` and compare the id field (basically, the equals method should simply do `return id.equals(other.getId())`, with the appropriate null-checks.

With equals comes and `hashCode()` - the two methods must always be implemented together, with the same fields.

And you need to override these methods, because the `removeAll` and `retainAll` methods work by iterating the collections and comparing the existing items with the items from the passed collection via `equals(..)`

Comment: Thanks! But I am not sure why hasCode() is needed. In my environment, it worked without hasCode(). I will check that.

Comment: yes, it will work in this case. But if you then decide to put your object in a HashMap, you'll experience unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your item class, e.g. like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj) return true;
    else if(obj instanceOf Item){ // implicit null check
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);
    }
    else return false;
}
```

I'm guessing it will work as expected after that.

Comment: Why do you use `result` while the value is 1 (37*1 will always be 37)?

Comment: @Kwadz this answer is 7 years old. These days my hashCode would be a oneliner: `return Objects.hash(id)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your `Item` class. If you don't then Java uses a default implementation of `equals` which is equivalent to `==`:

```
Item first = new Item(1);
Item second = new Item(1);
System.out.println(first == second); // Prints false, as expected: they are different objects.
System.out.println(first.equals(second)); // Prints false because of the default equals method.
```

If you implement `equals` correctly then the output will be `false` followed by `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate twice an Item even with the same parameter, you will have 2 differents objects.
Two solutions :

- use the same reference
- override equals from Object