# How to use Collections methods(removeAll() and retainAll()) for two objects. (objects are parent-child relation)

Tags: java, list, collections, apache-commons

I expected to result below but actually not. I would like to know how to show the differences between two Collections. (objects are parent and child relationship)
In this case, can I use standard method like removeAll() or can you recommend another approach like using apache-commons. Thanks.

```
CONSTRAINT
------------------------------
1.Item.class is unmodifiable(eg. I can not add equals method)
2.If id is same between two objects, they are assumed as same things.
------------------------------

EXPECTED
------------------------------
removed object are:
2
same object are:
1
3
add object are:
4
------------------------------

ACTUAL
------------------------------
removed object are:
1
2
3
same object are:
add object are:
1
3
4
------------------------------

package com.javastudy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionCompareToObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Item> before = new ArrayList<Item>();
        List<ItemEx> after = new ArrayList<ItemEx>();

        before.add(new Item(1L));
        before.add(new Item(2L)); // delete
        before.add(new Item(3L));

        after.add(new ItemEx(1L));
        after.add(new ItemEx(3L));
        after.add(new ItemEx(4L)); // added

        List<Item> removed = new ArrayList<Item>(before);
        removed.removeAll(after);

        System.out.println("removed objects are:");
        for(Item item : removed){
            System.out.println(item.getId());
        }

        List<Item> same = new ArrayList<Item>(before);
        same.retainAll(after);

        System.out.println("same objects are:");
        for(Item item : same){
            System.out.println(item.getId());
        }

        List<Item> added = new ArrayList<Item>(after);
        added.removeAll(before);

        System.out.println("add objects are:");
        for(Item item : added){
            System.out.println(item.getId());
        }

    }

}


package com.javastudy;

public class Item {

    private Long id;

    public Item(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

package com.javastudy;

public class ItemEx extends Item {

    private String name;

    public ItemEx(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: didn't you ask the same question an hour ago?

Comment: Unclear question, some more inputs are required

Comment: @Bozho, I believe so, it appears that the class ItemEx has been added, but the answer is the same. An auto generated equals() used by the OP last time may not be suitable to meet the requirements however.  Is the homework tags missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are quit right it is unclear. I will rewrite later. I just want to know how to compare two collections effectively. I found that if I use many for-loops, it worked as I expected. But maybe it is not sophisticated.

Comment: duplicate of [How to use Collections methods(removeAll() and retainAll()) for two objects.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461459/how-to-use-collections-methodsremoveall-and-retainall-for-two-objects)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java collections rely on the `equals` and `hashCode` methods (the latter is used by `HashMap`s, `HashSet`s and others).

If you want to be able to use the data structure capabilities of Java collections (such as `removeAll`, `retainAll` etc.), you need to supply objects with proper implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`.

If you can't modify the `Item` class, you can write a wrapper class with your own implementation of `equals`:

```
public class ItemWrapper {
    private final Item item;
    public ItemWrapper(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof ItemWrapper && item.getId().equals(((ItemWrapper) obj).item.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return item.getId().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Create a new `ItemWrapper` for each original `Item`, store the `ItemWrapper`s in Java collections, and use the required methods (`removeAll`/`retainAll`). Then iterate over the resulting collection and retrieve the `Item`s by calling each `ItemWrapper`'s `getItem()` method.

Your other option is to subclass `ArrayList`, but it seems like a more convoluted solution.

Yet another option is not to use Java collections for the remove/retain logic, implementing them yourself instead.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I will try to implement them myself base on remove/retain logic.

Comment: Or implement the Comparable interface and use TreeSet instead of HashSet.