# retainAll for many lists (Java)

Tags: java, intersection

I have a bunch of lists (`List<SomeClass>`) and I want to get the intersection. SomeClass looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private String a;
  private String b;

  // getters and setters
}
```

It should only become part of the intersection if the members a and b are equal. How can I do that?

I could probably use `Collection.retainAll(...)` somehow. But I have a big number of of List objects to compare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `equals` and `hasCode` methods accordingly for your class. See [Implementing equals](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17). These two methods implicitly reside in the `Object` instance, root of all classes, and they can be tuned/override to implement identification of instances following certain semantics, like in your case.

This [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462626/how-to-use-collections-methodsremoveall-and-retainall-for-two-objects-obj) addresses also this issue and you can find examples that implement the `equals` and `hasCode` methods.

As for how to reain all elements in N lists. You can just init a `HashSet` with the first list and iterate over the rest calling `retainAll`.