# Remove duplicates from two ArrayList of type ArrayList<Catalogue> Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

MyListView.java activity contains two arraylist: catalogueArrayList and catalogTempArrayList respectively.

```
ArrayList<Catalogue> catalogueArrayList = new ArrayList<Catalogue>();
ArrayList<Catalog> catalogTempArrayList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
```

In onCreate() activity, listview is populated using catalogueArrayList.  On update, new data is being pulled to second arrayList in background then added to catalogueArrayList. I don't want to clear my adapter before updating my listview. One idea is to remove duplicate items and use a temp arraylist to display new data. My problem is i don't know how to compare two arraylist, find the duplicates, remove them and create a third arraylist. Will this solution be efficient ? Will this consume times ?

Here is my catalogue class.

```
public class Catalogue {


    public String client_tel;
    public String product_name;
    public String product_price;
    public String product_desc;
    public String product_img;

    public Catalogue(String _client_tel, String _product_name,String _product_price,String _product_desc,String _product_img){

        this.client_tel=_client_tel;
        this.product_name=_product_name;
        this.product_price=_product_price;
        this.product_desc=_product_desc;
        this.product_img=_product_img;

    }
```

Catalog class is just a duplicate of this class.

**== Update ==**

Here is my pull update task

```
list.setOnUpdateTask(new OnUpdateTask() {

            public void updateBackground() {
                // simulate long times operation.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void updateUI() {

                catalogueArrayList.removeAll(catalogTempArrayList);
                efficientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void onUpdateStart() {

                new loadDataAsync().execute();

            }

        });
```

and my efficient adapter constructor

```
public EfficientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Catalog> d) {

        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


    }
```

Comment: When you compare two elements with different classes, the result should be false, this is not mandatory but unless you have a very very good reason, doing otherwise will only ask for problems.
---

Why do you have Catalogue and Catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

First, you should define `equals` function in your `Catalogue` and `Catalog` classes. Check if the object is Catalogue or Catalog class, then compare.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
   if (o == null){
        return false;
   }
   if (o instanceof Catalog){
        Catalog c = (Catalog) o;
        return c.product_name.equals(this.product_name)
   }
   if (o instanceof Catalogue){
        Catalogue cg = (Catalogue) o;
        return cg.product_name.equals(this.product_name)
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then you could use the `Iterator<Catalogue>` to check whether or not is in the `catalogTempArrayList` and remove it from the `catalogueArrayList`. Or just use the `removeAll` function from `ArrayList`.

```
catalogueArrayList.removeAll(catalogTempArrayList);
```

If you want to remove the `Catalog` instance from the `catalogTempArrayList`. Use this instead:

```
catalogTempArrayList.removeAll(catalogueArrayList);
```

These functions cost **O(n*m)**, being **n** and **m** the number of elements of the arrays.

Comment: this could be an example of equals class, just checking the name.

Comment: getting Syntax error on tokens, they can be merged to form instanceof error

Comment: yep, sorry. modified.

Comment: i am not receiving the update; catalogueArrayList is the old arraylist and catalogTempArrayList) is the new arraylist

Comment: What do you mean?, you want to remove the `Catalog` instances from `catalogTempArraList`, instead of the `Catalogue` instances from `catalogueArrayList`. Is it?

Comment: i want refreshed data received from catalogTempArraList  into Catalog without duplication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54422/discussion-between-adolaurion-and-dimitri).

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
catalogueArrayList.removeAll(catalogTempArrayList);
```

This will remove all the `Catalogue` items that the two `ArrayList` have in common from `catalogueArrayList`.

**Note:** There will be no change in `catalogTempArrayList`. It will still have all its items.

You should override the `equals` and `hashcode` method in your `Catalogue` class.

Comment: what do you mean by "You should override the equals and hashcode method in your Catalogue class."

Comment: Check this answer by @Eli Acherkan to see how to override `equals`and `hashcode` [How to use Collections methods(removeAll() and retainAll()) for two objects. (objects are parent-child relation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462626/how-to-use-collections-methodsremoveall-and-retainall-for-two-objects-ob)