# Java: RemoveAll(Collection c) returns false

Tags: java, list, collections, removeall

In my java code I have two `arrayList` one is `assignedRiders` and other is `nearestRiders`, and  I want to remove elements from `nearestRiders` list if it also exist in `assignedRiders` , for this I used following line but when I run this it returns me false even when they have same elements

**Code**

```
List<User> nearestRiders=new ArrayList<User>();
List<User> assignedRiders=new ArrayList<User>();
nearestRiders=riderLocationRepo.findNearestRiderList(orderRequest.getLatitudeShop(),
                    orderRequest.getLongitudeShop());
assignedRiders=orderAlredayAssigned();
Boolean dataChanhged=nearestRiders.removeAll(assignedRiders);
```

Comment: Does your User class override equals and hashcode?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Nope

Comment: @FirzaAhmed: It should.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Oh Thanks.. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: Because List operations like remove, removeAll, contains etc. all use the equals method to determine if two elements are the same.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Okay Thankyou for your help

Comment: If you don't implement the methods, your two user lists will use the memory address for comparison, and not their values. So for example if your orderAlreadyAssigned() method is going to a database and your nearestRiders is from a file (for example), the common riders effectively be the same object, just have the same values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Collections methods(removeAll() and retainAll()) for two objects. (objects are parent-child relation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462626/how-to-use-collections-methodsremoveall-and-retainall-for-two-objects-ob)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that :

```
for(User u : nearestRiders){
assignedRRiders.remove(u)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in those lists are not necessarily equal if they have equal values.

Source code for removeAll

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<?> e = iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
        if (c.contains(e.next())) {
            e.remove();
            modified = true;
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

It calls contains, which calls equalTo. This means you could override equalTo in the class of the objects you're trying to remove to check for a specific value such as GUID.